# How to trigger a BIOS interrupt (e.g. printing a character in TTY mode) on PowerPC/POWER architecture using asm?

Tags: assembly, interrupt, bios, powerpc

the title says it. I want to print a character to the screen on a machine with PowerPC/POWER architecture or basically just call some BIOS function. As I understand it usually matters which and how the BIOS is actually connected with the CPU, so let's say for a beginning I just want to focus on the machine qemu provides. I think I am not looking for the 'sc' command, actually I do not really know which kind of methods are used on a machine like this for doing something like that. As an example for what I want to be able to do let me provide the following x86 assembly snippet that shall print the character 'a' using a BIOS-Interrupt in TTY mode.

```
mov al, 0x97
mov bh, 0x00
mov bl, 0x07
mov ah, 0x0E
int 0x10
```

Thank you!

Comment: You'll need docs covering what the machine provides that's similar to a PC BIOS and invoke it according to the docs. There's really not much more (or less) to it than that.

Comment: Does that mean that e.g. PowerPC proto-boards and devkits are perhaps or might be binary (well 'functional') incompatible? (--  unlike most/all x86 PCs)

Comment: yes -- at least the few I've worked with were *not* compatible with much of anything but themselves and (perhaps) a few others in the same line from the same manufacturer.

Comment: okay, thank you very much. I thought there might be some 'virtual' standard regarding a basic issue like this.

Answer (score 2):

BIOS is specific to x86 architecture.  BIOS INT calls will not work on a Power architecture.

Your Power dev board probably has its own firmware, with it's own APIs.  You will need to consult the firmware development docs for your platform.

Comment: What PowerPC platform has a BIOS with a standard PC INT call API?

Comment: "BIOS is specific to x86 architecture" is not true unless you are referring specifically to the de-facto IBM PC BIOS, extended variously by third parties, and often not complying with the "standard". Apparently the term actually comes from CP/M, which also ran on the Z80. While the boot loader/ROM code may not have been called a "BIOS" on other platforms, it's effectively the same thing.

Comment: That's my point.  The term "BIOS" is specific to x86.  Other platforms have often have a boot firmware (e.g. U-boot), but it is generally not called "BIOS".

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a de-facto standard for the architecture external to the CPU (especially when you get around to crazy things like turning on little-endian mode, where the motherboard might be doing some byte-swapping of its own...).

There are also non-PC x86 architectures (probably various odd supercomputing architectures). Linux can be compiled for these.

If qemu provides additional hardware emulation modeled after PPC Macs, then there'll be a ROM image that supports booting, and also probably some basic box/text drawing as well as some sort of video access. To my knowledge, PPC Macs have never had anything like the PC's "text mode" (where the drawing is done with a font loaded on the video card); the OS X console scrolls reeeeeeally slowly.

Comment: What about the ones with VGA-compatible video hardware?  Don't those, at least, have text mode (whether or not the firmware provides an interface to it, and whether or not Darwin takes advantage of it)?  For example, this G5 iMac has a GeForce FX 5200...

Comment: @SamB: My understanding is that on "PC" hardware, the card contains a "video BIOS" which is essentially x86 code that knows how to talk to the video card, and something sets up the interrupt table to call this code on the right interrupts. Good luck getting any of these to run on PowerPC. Also note that while it may be the same GPU as a PC graphics card, the video BIOS might be on a different chip, and ultimately it's *not the same hardware* — for a long time "mac" graphics cards were an entirely different product due to endianness issues (why the driver couldn't fix this I have no idea...).